# appending to div get slower

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a drawing board using just `html/css/jquery` and the drawing is working fine. What I'm doing is catching the `mousemove` events and putting a dot(div) at every location the event fires, then I'm adding dots in between in places where the event wasn't firing to create a line.

This all works fine, but as I draw more, the appending of dots to the div is getting slower (or I should say, the drawing is getting a 'laggy' feel). I understand that the document is getting more divs appended to it, but why does it care if I'm just doing plain appends. I'm not doing any searches in the document for specific elements or anything.

here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u4mn2b84/14/

or is this not related to how many elements are in the document?

part of code:

```
$('#sketch-box').on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (isPerformingLeftMouseClick) {
            //var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
           var offset = $(this).offset();
           var currentMouseLeft = e.pageX - offset.left;
           var currentMouseTop = e.pageY - offset.top;
            var linkDotTemp = $(linkDot).clone();
            $(linkDotTemp).css('top', currentMouseTop);
            $(linkDotTemp).css('left', currentMouseLeft);
            if (lastMouseTop != null && lastMouseLeft != null) {
                drawLineInBetween(lastMouseTop, lastMouseLeft, currentMouseTop, currentMouseLeft);
            }
            $(this).append(linkDotTemp);
            lastMouseTop = currentMouseTop;
            lastMouseLeft = currentMouseLeft;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ending up with a LOT of divs on the page unnecessarily, and the browser is finding it harder and harder to render these the more you add (they are not designed to be used like this).

Even if you inspect element on your page in Chrome, the developer console really struggles when you start inspecting the dots.

I would recommend using HTML5 canvas instead.

[HTML5 Canvas w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)